# How to get the login ID of the current user logged in (WinForms)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a database named tbl_login and that stores the data of all the accounts. It also stores the roles of each user. For example, the logged-in user is a supplier, and if the supplier adds a new product, the login ID must be retrieved so I will know that the supplier that added a new product is the current logged in supplier.

This is what I tried so far, this is selecting from tbl_login

```
sqldataset = new DataSet();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tbl_login WHERE role='supplier'", con);
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapt.Fill(sqldataset);

            int loginID = Convert.ToInt32(sqldataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["loginID"]);
```

In this part of the code, I want to retrieve the current logged-in user

```
cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_Stocks(loginID, OrderQuantity, ProductID, Price, TotalPrice, OrderedDateAndTime, Status) VALUES (@loginID, @orderStocks, @prodIDInsert, @priceEach, @totalPrice, @orderDAT, @status)", con);


                int Order = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSalesRepOrder.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                int price = Convert.ToInt32(sqldataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"]);

                int total = price * Order;
                string stat = "Pending";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginID", loginID);//loginID that must be retrieved
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderStocks", Order);//Order Stocks
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodIDInsert", ProcID);//ProductID
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceEach", price);//Price
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPrice", total);//totalPrice
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDAT", dAt);//DateAndTime
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", stat);//Status
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: But where do you store the actual logged in user? If you store it in the table tbl_login how do you identify the logged in user between the other records?

Comment: in tbl_login, I added a role column, this is where I can differentiate if the user is a supplier, retailer or other account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what to do

I added a new class global which includes the ff.

```
public static int loginID;
public static String username;
public static String role;
```

And in the part that I want to retrieve the current logged-in user, I just called the class global. And it successfully did what I just want to do

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginID", global.loginID);//loginID that must be retrieved
```

In the login form, this must be declared:

```
global.loginID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["loginID"].ToString().Trim());
global.username = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString().Trim();
global.role = dt.Rows[0]["role"].ToString().Trim();
```